# <EOF>Exception while creating Derby table

Tags: java, sql, derby, eof

Getting an  exception ( SQL Syntax Error).

New to programming DB,been looking everywhere but cant seem to pinpoint,

I understand I have some issues with executing the statement since the error log tells me error line is-

```
Statement stmt= con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

the method:

```
public static void createTable(String name) {

        String url= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/newDB;create=true";

        try (Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url)){

            String sql="create table "+name+" (ID int, Name varchar(20)";
            Statement stmt= con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Table Created");

        }catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Table creation interupted");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Been trying various ways to write this, in main method, without 'create=true',
with Prepared Statement but nothing seem to work.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

The pedantic compiler is saying your Create Table SQL is not properly closed, it should be something like this:

```
create table some_table (ID int, Name varchar(20))
```

Comment: I cant believe  this was my mistake :(  you;re correct, thank you! Had a missing ')'

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Had a missing ')', with the string not telling me the mistake.
compiled and worked.
Cant believe I missed it.

thanks tjames6123